# CSS background-size not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and have a jumbotron header at the top of my page. I want an image based background for this jumbotron. I am attempting to use

```
background-size: cover;
```

My understanding of this, would be that if the size of the container (in this case the jumbotron) is the same size as the image (i.e, if the image was 1280x350 and the size of the container for that viewport was 1280x350) then the image would be displayed without any cropping or zooming. If the viewport was larger, it would begin to zoom, and if the viewport smaller, it would begin to cut bits of the image out.

This is not what I am getting, with an image of resolution the same size as a viewport on a 1080p screen (1920x350 in this case) my image is getting massively zoomed in. The image is only in its "neutral" state at a viewport size of width 1042 or so, which makes no sense considering the image is 1920 wide.

Any help appreciated as to what's going on here.

**EDIT: Here is full CSS:**

```
    .jumbotron{
          background-size: cover;
          background-image: url("../../test.jpg");
          border-radius: 0rem;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
     }
```

EDIT 2: After further investigation, it appears to be something to do with image height. It appears to be prioritising image height over width.

Comment: Please post your HTML and rest of your CSS to your question. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Try background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;

Comment: I've added full CSS above, essentially am doing the above Sean. I will work on a codepen example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smaller image will not fit in larger view port without `zoom`. You can use [responsive images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) based on view port. You can use two new attributes — `srcset` and `sizes` — to provide several additional source images along with hints to help the browser pick the right one. [Test link](https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/multimedia-and-embedding/responsive-images/responsive.html) and [source code](https://github.com/mdn/learning-area/blob/master/html/multimedia-and-embedding/responsive-images/responsive.html).

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg"
     alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

> Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it to my liking in the end cropping it and shirnking it using Paint.Net. Now I have to try and get the background-fixed attribute to work.